# how to show feedback on new textarea everytime?

Tags: php

i fetched data from db and show in textarea.Data of all person appears in one textarea.i want to show each persons data on new textarea everytime.what should i do?

```
<form>
        <marquee><textarea class="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" >
        <?php
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","feedback");
        if($conn-> connect_error){
          die("Connection field:". $conn-> connection_error);
        }
        $sql="SELECT customer,restuarant,title,comment from fedbk";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
           while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo  $row["customer"]."\n"; 
              echo $row["restuarant"]."\n".$row["title"]."\n".$row["comment"]."\n";
           } 
        } else {
           echo"0 result";
        }
        $conn->close()
  ?>
 </textarea></marquee>
</form>
```

Comment: put the textarea inside the loop

Comment: if($result->num_rows>0){
       while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
  <marquee><textarea class="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" >
  echo  $row["customer"]."\n"; 
  echo $row["restuarant"]."\n".$row["title"]."\n".$row["comment"]."\n";
     }  </textarea></marquee>  
   }else {
   echo"0 result";
}
 $conn->close()

Comment: but it shows error of "unexpected<"

Comment: `echo '<marquee><textarea class="tex....';` - take care of the right quotes there (or escape them)

Comment: of course also the `</textarea></marquee>` needs to be in the loop then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is, you call single textarea , and showed all the customer value in it. But you want to show individual textarea for each customer. So You can do this like

```
<form>
        <marquee>
        <?php
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","feedback");
        if($conn-> connect_error){
          die("Connection field:". $conn-> connection_error);
        }
        $sql="SELECT customer,restuarant,title,comment from fedbk";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
           while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo '<textarea class="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" >';
              echo  $row["customer"]."\n"; 
              echo $row["restuarant"]."\n".$row["title"]."\n".$row["comment"]."\n";
              echo '</textarea></br>';
           } 
        } else {
           echo"0 result";
        }
        $conn->close()
  ?>
 </marquee>
</form>
```

BTW, marquee is obsolete according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee).

Comment: then what to use instead of marquee

Comment: and all textarea appears in 1 line how to show only 1 textarea in 1 line

Comment: I don't know any alternative of marquee.

To show one text area in one line, add a line break. I have updated my code. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","feedback");
        if($conn-> connect_error){
          die("Connection field:". $conn-> connection_error);
        }
        $sql="SELECT customer,restuarant,title,comment from fedbk";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
           while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            <textarea class="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" >
          echo  $row["customer"]."\n"; 
              echo $row["restuarant"]."\n".$row["title"]."\n".$row["comment"]."\n"; 
            </textarea>
           } 
        } else {
           echo"0 result";
        }
        $conn->close()
  ?>
```